# java ~ Unable to qualify condition in an if statement

Tags: java, generics, singly-linked-list

I am using Singly_Linked_List with generics and storing an object of class cycles and cycle has just one parameter price, so getElement() will be returning price. But list.contains(walk.getElement()) always return false. I am getting trouble in toString method. Whole Implementation is given below.

```
public String toString() {    
    ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Node<E> walk = head;
    while (walk != null) {
        if (!list.contains(walk.getElement()))
            list.add(walk.getElement());
        walk = walk.getNext();
    }
    return list.toString();
}
```

whole list implementation:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 public class Singly_Linked_List<E> {
  class Node<E> {
    private E element;
    private Node<E> next;

    Node(E element, Node<E> next) {
        this.element = element;
        this.next = next;
    }

    void setNext(Node<E> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    E getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    Node<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }
 }

private Node<E> tail;
private Node<E> head;
private int size = 0;

Singly_Linked_List() {
}

int getSize() {
    return size;
}

boolean isEmpty() {
    return getSize() == 0;
}

void addFirst(E element) {
    head = new Node<E>(element, head);
    if (isEmpty())
        tail = head;
    size++;
}

void addLast(E element) {
    Node<E> node = new Node<E>(element, null);
    if (isEmpty())
        head = node;
    else
        tail.setNext(node);
    tail = node;
    size++;
}

E first() {
    if (isEmpty())
        return null;
    return head.getElement();
}

E last() {
    if (isEmpty())
        return null;
    return tail.getElement();
}

E removeFirst() {
    if (isEmpty()) return null;
    E answer = head.getElement();
    head = head.getNext();
    if (head == tail)
        tail = null;
    size--;
    return answer;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Node<E> walk = head;
    while (walk != null) {
        if (!list.contains(walk.getElement()))
            list.add(walk.getElement());
        walk = walk.getNext();
    }
    return list.toString();
}
```

}

Cycle class implementation :

```
public class Cycle{
 private int price;


 Cycle(int price) {
     this.price = price;
 }

 int getPrice() {
     return this.price;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
     return "" + this.price;
 }

 public boolean equals(Cycle cycle) {
     return this.getPrice() == cycle.getPrice();
 }
}
```

Comment: show object and  list implementation please.

Comment: `list` is empty. Why would it be expected to contain something?

Comment: What type does `getElement()` return?  Is it perhaps a custom class that isn't correctly implementing `equals()`?

Comment: @jsheeran, first time it is empty but after that it will not be empty

Comment: @KevinAnderson, getElement() will return Cycle object type.

Comment: @Black.Jack edited.

Comment: Post your Cycle class, including .equals()

Comment: @IanMc cycle class Posted.

Comment: Is the problem that the list created in toString() contains duplicates?  What is list.size() after walk is iterated, and what do you expect list.size() to be?  It looks like you are trying to capture all the unique elements (by price) that exist in the linked list - is this true?  Is order important?

Comment: @IanMc, order doesnot matter, it should be unique. list.size() will be changing according to driver method, if i am removing or adding unique elements.

Comment: Can you provide a tangible problem:  For example if your linked list contains 4 Node<Cycle>s, with prices 10, 15, 15, 20 - what is happening in toString() that is a defect?  The logic you have should create a list with 3 Cycle objects (10, 15, 20) - what is happening that is wrong?

Comment: @IanMc, it is creating list with 4 cycle objects (10,15,15,20)

Comment: I have posted the fix; can you kindly try it and mark it if your issue is resolve.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you do in the toString method is initialise a local variable list as a new ArrayList. That means list is empty at the start of each toString call. That is why list.contains(...) is returning false allways.

If your goal is to print out the unique elements, you better use a Set instead of a List. Something like:

```
public String toString() {
    Set<E> s = new HashSet<>();
    Node<E> walk = head;

    while (walk != null) {
      // No need to check if element exists. Set can only contain 
      // unique elements
      s.add(walk.getElement());
      walk = walk.getNext();
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Don't forget to implement good equals/ hashcode methods for the Node class. The uniqueness is based on that.

Comment: Because I need to call toString() method, at various time and the Singly_Linked_List will be changed everytime, so I created ArrayList inside the method. But I think Set will be a better option\

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting unexpected behaviour (duplicates) in your list (and set for that matter) is because you have an incorrect equals() method.  Java requires that you pass an Object to equals.  Below are two fixes that should fix your issue

1. The simple fix - minimal change to your code to make it work (better is #2 below)

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       Cycle cycle = (Cycle)o;
       return this.getPrice() == cycle.getPrice();
   }
   ```
2. The preferred equals method

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (this == obj)
           return true;
       if (obj == null)
           return false;
       if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
           return false;
       Cycle other = (Cycle) obj;
       if (price != other.price)
           return false;
       return true;
   }
   ```

Your IDE may be able to create equals() for you.  It is good practice to create hashCode() as well when you create equals() for use with sets, maps, etc.